# Enable Cross Domain IIS Web Deploy

Tags: iis, cross-domain, webdeploy

Is it possible to use Web Deploy (wmsvc) across domains?  That is, can I deploy from my dev box/build server in one domain onto a web server in another?  I am able to do this inside the same domain so I know that I do have the web deployment service configured properly.  However from another domain I can't even get the https://severname.domain.com:8172/msdeploy.axd to challenge for credentials.

Comment: Is the "other" domain outside your firewall?

Comment: I don't believe so, I am able to hit other websites on the same server that the web deploy service is running on.

Comment: The websites are exposed via port 80, a port commonly opened on firewalls. The WMSVC is exposed on 8172, which is specific to it.

Answer (score 1):

The short answer is yes.

WMSVC exposes itself on port 8172, but it uses the https protocol.  So long as you have a direct way to get from one network to the other, over that port, it will work.

We run all of our webservers on a DMZ, which is an isolated network with separate DNS, active directory servers, etc.  I can directly deploy from my build server (on the *.hq network) to the *.dmz.com server over port 8172.

However, I did have to communicate this requirement to the networking group so that they could allow port 8172 to pass through our firewall.  Also, I wasn't able to set up web deploy with automatic Windows Auth because the two networks had different domains and different sets of users.